# Getting the path of %AppData% in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting

How can I get the path for the application data directory (e.g. `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming`) in PowerShell?

Comment: Also see list here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables

Answer (score 256, accepted):

This is the shortest way:

```
$env:APPDATA
```

or for local app data:

```
$env:LOCALAPPDATA
```

Comment: It works in `cd $env:APPDATA`

Answer (score 16):

To get the AppData directory, use the `GetFolderPath` method:

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::ApplicationData)
```

Or as Andy mentions in his comment, simply:

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath('ApplicationData')
```

Comment: Slightly shorter version: `[Environment]::GetFolderPath('ApplicationData')`

Comment: all this gives me is 'ApplicationData', not the path.

Comment: How to list all Special Folder variable?

Comment: Impressively, this is the better option because it even works on Linux, via PowerShell core, and returns the correct value — `$HOME/.config`!

Answer (score 6):

```
$TempInstallerPath="$Env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Downloaded Installations"
if(Test-Path $TempInstallerPath)
{
    Remove-Item "$TempInstallerPath\*" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction 0
}
```