# extracting a .zip file into %AppData%\

Tags: powershell, userappdatapath

I am looking to use the same **Expand-Archive** Powershell cmd to unzip the files but instead of using a local location for eg C:\Program Files\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder" I am trying to extract the zip file into the logged on users profile so that the zip file will unpack it's payload into the users %APPDATA%\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder

I have amended the -DestinationPath but it fails to unzip the contents into the users profile.but seems to just create a file named  %APPDATA%

can anybody help ?

$SourcePath = "nameoffile.zip"
$Destination = "C:\Program Files\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder"
Expand-Archive -Path $SourcePath -DestinationPath $Destination –Force
write-host "nameofzipfile unzipped successfully"

Comment: Hi Craig. Simply change the destination.

Comment: Thanks for your response Doug changing the destination does not appear to work it seems to create a folder in the location named %appdata%\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder rather than actually extracting the zip file contents into that location.

Comment: `%APPDATA%` means just a `string` to PowerShell, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10132925/15339544

Comment: %appdata% is a cmd environment variable, not powershell. Your question isn’t “how do I access environment variables in powershell”

Answer (score 1):

`%appdata%` is a environment variable used by batch (cmd). if you want to use the same reference in powershell you use $env:appdata

`$Destination = "$env:appdata\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder"`